# Pandas keyError : ('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, indexing

I am a beginner in the field of Machine Learning. I have started with the below code:

```
#import modules
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

#using required data frames
df = df[['Adj.Open','Adj.High','Adj.Low','Adj.Close','Adj.Volume',]]

#getting percent change in High and Low at closing
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj.High'] - df['Adj.Close']) / df['Adj.Close'] * 100.0

#getting percent change in price
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj.Close'] - df['Adj.Open']) / df['Adj.Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj.Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj.Volume']]

print(df.head())
```

But I am getting indexing error:

```
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])

KeyError: "['Adj.Open' 'Adj.High' 'Adj.Low' 'Adj.Close' 'Adj.Volume'] not in index"
```

How to fix this?

Comment: After `df = quandl.get...` what does `df.columns` display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your API source data there is this a white blank after `.`

```
df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I got my error and solution.

Comment: @karanrp I just do not have the habit copy whole code here.. ok ,fine , happy coding

Comment: No, it's ok. This place is for the solution. And you have pointed solution. It's great.

Answer (score 1):

There are whitespaces after every `.`, see code below

```
import pandas as pd

import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

#using required data frames
df=df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low', 'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]

#getting percent change in High and Low at closing
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0

#getting percent change in price
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]

print(df.head())



          Adj. Close    HL_PCT  PCT_change  Adj. Volume
Date                                                     
2004-08-19   50.322842  3.712563    0.324968   44659000.0
2004-08-20   54.322689  0.710922    7.227007   22834300.0
2004-08-23   54.869377  3.729433   -1.227880   18256100.0
2004-08-24   52.597363  6.417469   -5.726357   15247300.0
2004-08-25   53.164113  1.886792    1.183658    9188600.0
```